# how do i display array names in root of dictionary

Tags: uitableview, plist, root

Hi I have a plist file that I am reading from its hiarchy is like so:

Root - Dictionary
Date1 array (filled with dictionaries)
Date2 array (filled with dictionaries)
etc

How do I fill my UITableView with the array titles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the keys of the root `NSDictionary` using the `allKeys` method:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyData" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *rootDict = [[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path] autorelease];

NSLog(@"%@", [[rootDict allKeys] objectAtIndex:0]); // Should return Date1Array
```

Therefore, in your UITableViewDataSource method, you can access the correct key:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

// Assumes the plist's root dictionary has been retained using a property:
NSString *arrayName = [[self.rootDict allKeys] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

//... configure cell

}
```

Comment: Bingo. Excellent response. Thank you.